# When Does the Blood Arcanist Gain the Arcanist Exploit Class Feature?

Tags: pathfinder-1e

The [Blood Arcanist](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/hybrid-classes/arcanist/archetypes/paizo---arcanist-archetypes/blood-arcanist/) loses her Arcanist Exploits at the 1st, 3rd, 9th, and 15th level.  My question is if this also means that the Blood Arcanist does not count as a character that possesses the Arcanist Exploit class feature until 5th level.  I ask because I was considering taking [Extra Arcanist Exploit](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/general-feats/extra-arcanist-exploit) at 1st and 3rd level, but I wasn't sure if doing so would be legal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think that's legal by the RAW.  The rules on [archetypes](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/class-archetypes) specifically say that:

> A character who takes an alternate class feature does not count as having the class feature that was replaced for the purposes of meeting any requirements or prerequisites.

The wording of the blood arcanist ability states that:

> This ability replaces the arcanist exploits gained at 1st, 3rd, 9th, and 15th levels

At 1st-4th level you have not been granted the arcanist exploit class feature, you don't qualify for the feat.

So RAW I don't see much wriggle room.  But since the Blood Arcanist does *eventually* get exploits, and they function off your full, normal arcanist level, I don't think there'd be any balance reason to enforce this rule.

Comment: I can also technically retrain whatever feats I get at 1st and 3rd level when I reach 5th level, yes?

Comment: @user3735278 I suppose so, although that sort of [general retraining](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/basics-ability-scores/more-character-options/retraining) is an optional rule, and so entirely up to the DM.  (Some classes, like the fighter, specifically let you retrain your bonus feats as part of their core functionality, but the general rules are optional.)

Comment: Not sure the Blood Arcanist is considered as losing the Arcanist Exploit class feature. It is modified, but he technically still has the feature.

Comment: ...Corroborating evidence *for* "if you lose a feature like this you don't have it": Havocker Witch.  Evidence against: ...I'm not sure that RAW you *couldn't* pick up exactly one Witch Hex if you gained a feat w/ your Witch 1; it says "from second level on" in the text of what's being replaced.